# Errno 13: Permission denied: 'celerybeat-schedule' with Celery running on AWS ECS and SQS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

I have a separate Celery Beat and Work service running in ECS.  The worker appears to be connecting to SQS fine.  The Beat on the other hand is giving me trouble.  I used these instructions as a template for what I am doing.

https://dev.to/daiquiri_team/deploying-django-application-on-aws-with-terraform-setting-up-celery-and-sqs-38ik

I deviated a little bit because I already had an existing Terraform/Django project running within AWS.  The Django project is also on ECS.

I am having difficulty knowing what to be looking for because the error is rather vague.  Why would the schedule create a Permissions denied?  Is the Beat trying to write to SQS? I currently have 4 queues.

I am executing the command below from the container definition:

`celery -A backend beat`

I also am running the following in my container definition because I read that ECS is always run as root.

```
{"name": "C_FORCE_ROOT", "value": "true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Celery Beat documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) (under the Starting the Scheduler section):

> Beat needs to store the last run times of the tasks in a local database file (named celerybeat-schedule by default), so it needs access to write in the current directory, or alternatively you can specify a custom location for this file:
>
> ```
> celery -A proj beat -s /home/celery/var/run/celerybeat-schedule
> ```

So I think you just need to provide a path to which the container can write the file via the `-s` flag.